# How to change languages with alt+shift

Tags: 13.04, shortcut-keys, language-support

I use 3 languages when I brows the internet and changing it from the top panel is quite disturbing on windows you can changed the languages with pressing alt+shift so can I some how do the same on ubuntu

thank you in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into System Settings --> Keyboard Layout

[image]

Click on Options

[image]

Go to Key(s) to Change Layout, and choose <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>

[image]